# iOS: Exclude players from GKTurnBasedMatch

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

I am building a 2 player game. I am using GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController to start matches. I would like to ensure that players can only have one game vs the same player.

Currently if a player starts a game with someone they already have I just delete the game. This has 2 issues

1. The other player gets notifications about the newly deleted game
2. If the game was created by auto-match then the other user is removed from the auto-match queue.

So I would like to know...

1. Is there a way to exclude players in the GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController
2. Is there a way to remove a player from a game that allows the game to look for a new auto-match player?

Comment: did you ever find out if this was possible?